# News/message replay at specific times

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a List objects. Each NewsItem has 2 properties:
String Headline { get; set; }
DateTime PostedOn { get; set; }

I'm trying to write a "replay" code that retrieves all yesterday's news items from DB and then publishes each one of them at the exact (or nearly exact) time they were originally posted, and then display them as a live feed in a WPF app.

I understand that scheduling those posts could be done with  System.Threaing.Timer. E.g. find the next post with PostedOn.Time > Datetime.Now.Time, schedule Timer, and in timer_Elapsed method raise the Posted event of some sort.

However I'm wondering if there is a more "modern" way of doing it in C#, e.g. with Tasks or Reactive Extensions / Observables. I've noticed there is Observable.Replay method but I can't seem to find any examples. Not sure if it's even applicable in this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did any of our answers help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Quartz.Net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) which is an open sourced c# scheduler library.

Check out this [Quick Start](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html). At the end in public class HelloJob, you can replace that object with something that will publish/display them as a live feed in a WPF app.

Answer (score 0):

You are after some very simple functionality... can you really not develop it yourself? Let's break it down... first, you need a collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<NewsItem> newsItems = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem>()
```

Fill your collection with the day's items (ordered by `PostedOn`)... something like this:

```
newsItems = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem>(
    DataProvider.GetNewsItemsFor(someDate).OrderBy(n => n.PostedOn));
```

Now you just need a `DispatcherTimer` to alert you to when the next item needs to be shown... assuming that you have correctly initialised your timer, you could do this:

```
timer.Interval = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Subtract(nextNewsItem.PostedOn);
```

You might need to tweak the code above a bit, but the basic idea is that you are just comparing the time today with the time yesterday and when the relevant time comes around, the `Timer_Tick` event handler will be called and then you can display the item and set the `timer.Interval` to the amount of time until the next item needs to be displayed.